# etherscan showing 0 balance, transaction showing as success, but balance in my contract as 0

Tags: solidity, remix, ether, contract-deployment, smart-contract-wallets

Not sure why etherscan.io showing as 0 balance.
My Transaction hash# "0x2653135e31407726a25dd8d304878578cdfcc7d69a2b319d1aca4a37ed66956a" is showing as susccess with 0.47 eth. but when i check my contract(To address) its showing as 0 balance. Any inputs to back track this appreciated.

Comment: Your ETH went to this address https://etherscan.io/address/0xe99ffccd4ac8ff7e7ba40dec214054eed1e3e78c. I'm not sure what you were trying to do

Answer (score 0):

etherscan.io/address/0xe99ffccd4ac8ff7e7ba40dec214054eed1e3e78c  --- this is an internal transaction which is showing under my contract/transaction hash.
iam using remix ide , but its not showing the balance due to its being under interna trxns. is there a limit in etherscan to move eth if its less than 0.5eth as internal trxn!
I see several of transactions showing in Internal trxn under this address(0xe99ffccd4ac8ff7e7ba40dec214054eed1e3e78c).

Comment: There's no limit on the ETH amount. The internal trx means that the contract you called moved the ETH to address 0xe99... If you think this was unintentional, you can share the code of your contract by editing the question. Otherwise we can't tell what you were trying to do.

Comment: code is from free source code avaialble ..https://codepastes.com/raw/HHPCwR

Comment: yes it's a common scam. Don't send crypto to contracts you don't understand, especially these MEV contracts you find around.

Comment: appreciate for the response.